# Show comments before comment form in add/show 3 more comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

In questions with more than five comments, the first five are shown and the rest hidden under a 'add/show x more comments'.

When you click that link, you are first shown the comment textarea to add your own comment and then you have to click the link again to see the 'x more comments'.

Shouldn't we be shown the comments first then the textarea?

**EDIT**
This only happens in slow connections, I guess as the comments load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form and hidden comments are meant to load **at the same time**. You don't need to click 'add / show x more comments' twice.

As you noted, with a slow connection, fetching the comments will take more time than displaying the add comment form. That is the cause.

<sub>[For convenience, example here](https://askubuntu.com/a/94963/176889)</sub>

Comment: Yeah. I realised that after sometime of head scratching.